# Application Error on Heroku: An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Have a working rails app on development but issue deployed.  Was recently working but after doing a clouldmailin add on seemed to cause some dependencies issues?   Any help with understanding the issue in the logs would be greatly appreciated.

```
2012-01-11T23:35:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
    2012-01-11T23:35:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    2012-01-11T23:35:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top  (required)>'
    2012-01-11T23:35:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `require'
    2012-01-11T23:35:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
    2012-01-11T23:35:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    2012-01-11T23:35:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    2012-01-11T23:35:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
    2012-01-11T23:35:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    2012-01-11T23:35:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    2012-01-11T23:35:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    2012-01-11T23:35:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    2012-01-11T23:35:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    2012-01-11T23:35:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    2012-01-11T23:35:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    2012-01-11T23:35:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
    2012-01-11T23:35:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r   ailties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
    2012-01-11T23:35:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
    2012-01-11T23:35:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    2012-01-11T23:35:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
    2012-01-11T23:35:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
    2012-01-11T23:35:08+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2012-01-11T23:35:08+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
    2012-01-11T23:45:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
    2012-01-11T23:45:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
    2012-01-11T23:45:06+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec     rails   server -p 52293`
    2012-01-11T23:45:09+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2012-01-11T23:45:09+00:00 app[web.1]:   gem install bson_ext
    2012-01-11T23:45:09+00:00 app[web.1]:   You can install the extension as follows:
    2012-01-11T23:45:09+00:00 app[web.1]:   bson_ext gem is in your load path and that the  bson_ext and mongo gems are of the same version.
    2012-01-11T23:45:09+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2012-01-11T23:45:09+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2012-01-11T23:45:09+00:00 app[web.1]: **Notice: C extension not loaded. This is required    for optimum MongoDB Ruby driver performance.
    2012-01-11T23:45:09+00:00 app[web.1]:   If you continue to receive this message after   installing, make sure that the
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.1.3 application starting in production on  http://0.0.0.0:52293
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/   activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require': /app/app/controllers/  email_controllers.rb:1: class/module name must be CONSTANT (SyntaxError)
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]: class emailcontroller < applicationcontroller
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:                        ^
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/email_controllers.rb:3: syntax   error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:                        ^
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/email_controllers.rb:8: syntax   error, unexpected tLBRACK, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:    @inbound_email = InboundEmail.new(:text =>     params ["text"],
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                       ^
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/email_controllers.rb:8: syntax   error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:                           ^
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:                     :to => clean_Field(params["to"]),
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/email_controllers.rb:10: syntax  error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/email_controllers.rb:13: syntax  error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/email_controllers.rb:22: syntax  error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:       flash [:notice] = "ooops we had an error"
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:                        ^
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/email_controllers.rb:10: syntax  error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:    skip_before_filters: verify_authenticity_token
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:302:in `depend_on'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `require_dependency'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:417:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `block in eager_load!'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `each'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `each'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/email_controllers.rb:11: syntax  error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `eager_load!'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:51:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r   ailties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r   ailties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/r   ailties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top  (required)>'
        2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in  <main>'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `require'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/    railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
    2012-01-11T23:45:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
    2012-01-11T23:45:17+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
    2012-01-11T23:45:16+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2012-01-11T23:45:21+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET    www.domain.me/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
    2012-01-11T23:45:21+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET    www.domain.me/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Is it just that `class emailcontroller < applicationcontroller` should be `class EmailController < ApplicationController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @muistooshort said and as the log points out, the class name needs to be capitalized, since that's how ruby recognizes which are classes and types of objects versus regular variable names or method calls.

This is the relevant piece of your log: class/module name must be CONSTANT

So, change your email controller class declaration to:

```
class EmailController < ApplicationController
```

and re-deploy.